# Create an array of search results

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can i get the name in the picture below?

```
  return testData.then((data) => {
    console.log(data)
    var results = [];
    var toSearch = params.suggestTerm;
    data = data["data"]["0"];
    console.log("data: ", data["0"])
    for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
      if(data[i]["name"].indexOf(toSearch)!=-1) {
        results.push(data[i]);
      }
    }
```

result of console.log(data)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to do this :`data = data["data"]["0"];`. If you are doing that you are assigning data to be the first object from the nested list. It is not an array anymore.

Just get the list in another `variable` and access that:

```
 let list = data.data;
 for(var i=0; i<list.length; i++) {
      if(list[i]["name"].indexOf(toSearch) !== -1) {
        results.push(list[i]);
      }
    }
```

The `indexOf()` search will be case sensitive. If that is not what you want, you can lowercase and search.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are looking to have an array only containing items that have `name` values in your `toSearch` string.  If that's the case, you could use `Array.filter()` similar to:

```
return testData.then((data) => {
    console.log(data)
    var results = [];
    var toSearch = params.suggestTerm;
    if (data && data.data && data.data.length > 0){
        results = data.data.filter(item =>
            item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(toSearch.toLowerCase()) > -1
       )
    return results;
}
```

This example searches case insensitive.  If you wish for a case sensitive search, remove the `.toLowerCase()`

See [Array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'filter')

Comment: hello should i delete the loop? apply the filter?

Comment: If you are getting an inability to filter, then data.data is not an array.  Added an if statement to check if data is defined.  Yes, the filter would replace your for loop.